# exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 13 (Permission denied)

Tags: linux, nfs, kubernetes, ownership

When I am using this command to check NFS:

```
exportfs -a
```

... it shows this error:

```
[miao@k8sslave3 lib]$ exportfs -a
exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 13 (Permission denied)
exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 13 (Permission denied)
exportfs: can't lock /var/lib/nfs/etab for writing
```

I am checking the `/var/lib/nfs` folder and find the owner is root. So why is the `/var/lib/nfs` folder owned by root when I use the `miao` user to install NFS? What should I do to fix this problem? Now, this NFS shared folder is writable by the Kubernetes pod, and the root user starts the `kubelet` process.